# Minimize workbook/sheet but keep form opened

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to minimize a workbook/sheet but able to keep the form opened up?
I have tried the code:

```
application.visible=false
```

and

```
userform1.show vbmodeless
```

But this hides the all active workbooks and the tool bar ribbon thing disappears as well. Is there a way to minimize the workbook but keep the ribbon showing and form opened as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Tested on Excel 2010*

```
Sub Test()

    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

This will minimize the all the workbooks in Excel but will keep the ribbon and any userforms visible, if you dont have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` then people will be able to see the workbooks in the bottom left of Excel.

---

If you want to just minimize a single workbook you can use the code below

*[Credit to this answer on SO for the minimizing specific workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11357540/5784703)*

```
Sub test()

    Dim wbName As Window

    Set wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1)'You can use Windows("[Workbook Name]") as well

    wbName.Visible = False
    wbName.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Let me know if you need anything clarified

Comment: for the line of "ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False", what does the "windows(1)" mean? what does the 1 represent?

Comment: When you open multiple workbooks they all stay in a singlw window (generally), the 1 represents which order they were opened in essentially

Comment: so what if I only want to minimize a specific workbook? how do I find out the number for it or can I somehow do "Workbook("nameofworkbook")"?

Comment: I updated my answer, this should cover your question. As to why I have set the `Activeworkbook.Windows()` I was playing around with it a bit more and found you wouldnt make the workbook visible again using `.Visible= True`