# Can we assign a Win + D Function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a userform where i have disabled X (close button) on the forms and have added two buttons one of which will run a sendkey function to do ALt+Tab. For the other one I want to assign Win+D

The Win + D not seems to be working, it just activates Windows but not capturing the D. Following is the code:

```
Application.SendKeys ("^{ESC}D")
```

I am not sure if this is even possible. I tried the internet search over and over but wasn't fruitful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimize workbook/sheet but keep form opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679441/minimize-workbook-sheet-but-keep-form-opened)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use Excel *Application.SendKeys* you could use *Shell.Application*

**Excel Macro**

```
Sub ShowDesktop()

    CreateObject("Shell.Application").MinimizeAll

End Sub
```