# Hide only one workbook and show all other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with userform. I want to hide the workbook whenever I open the file and shows only userform. I need to hide only one workbook and show all other workbook and if I click on userform it should run from the workbook where the code is written. I used the following commands but it hides all the other workbooks.

```
application.visible= true

ActiveWindow.Visible = False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding active workbook programmatically in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354456/hiding-active-workbook-programmatically-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False
```

Comment: i did this but it still shows the excel window.i want to hide the window completely and shows when other workbook opens. secondly if i open other work and clik on my userform it shows an error i-e subscript out of range. how to fix it?